# HTML CSS border not working good in Safari Browser

Tags: html, css, border

You can see this in safari browser on border top white lines. How can I solve this?

CODE:

**CSS**

```
.row-number5{
border-radius: 100%;
min-width: 1.25em;
max-width: 1.25em;
height: 1.1em;
padding: 0.55em;
border-style: none;
border-bottom-style: dotted;
border-bottom-color: cornsilk;
align-self: center;
border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row"><div class="row-number5">5# </div></div>
```

**Safari**

[image: Safari Browser]

**Opera**(You can see works perfectly in Opera Browser.)

[image: Opera Browser]

Comment: I made some tests, and I can reproduce your issue (it's working on chrome too), but I don't have any clues... I tried with transparent border on left/top/right, with different styles but it's not working...

Comment: One solution could be to use `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements, and hide the top of your border with a background-colored element, but it's not the nicest way to do that...